# How to test a asp.net web service deployed on server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

i want to test a asp.net web service which is deployed on server , i tested it on local server , but now i deployed it on server, now i want to test it without using web application , Is there any way to test my web service? any one?please help

when i tried to access the web service deployed on server , it shows this message

The test form is only available for requests from the local machine.

Comment: When you say test you mean regression testing (unit test etc) or just to see **once** if it works?

Comment: Don't ask such questions here. If you have coding related problems then we are here. For this kind of question you need to google it ..... Nothing else..

Comment: @PantelisNatsiavas i just want to see that it works or not

Answer (score 0):

[SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) is probably what you are looking for. It is platform independent. It can test web services, regardless of the platform use to develop them.

If you already have a more general mechanism for regression testing (using unit tests for example) you should follow a more complex path. You should create a mock client for the specific web service and then check the results returned by the actual web service. This is a more complex scenario.

Hope I helped!

Comment: how to use SOAP UI , can u generally explain it ?

Comment: SOAP UI has a very intuitive user interface and is very easy to use. I don't have anything to explain really... I would suggest to download it and see.